# keyboard shortcut to switch to next window

Tags: shortcut-keys, xdotool

How can I configure shortcut to switch to next window? I use Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME. I know that I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but pressing It again returns me to previous window instead of next.

Holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> more times, or using arrows is not suitable for me as I want to use this shortcut with xdotool.

Maybe there is some way to prevent windows reordering when I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in order to not return to previous window?

Comment: That behavior is obvious. Whenever you switch windows the current window becomes *Window 1* and the window you switched from becomes *Window 2*. When again you hit Alt+Tab it switches to *Window 2* which was the window you were on earlier. So you are back to the *previous window*. Sounds a little bit confusing. :-)

Comment: @Kulfy I agree, but If I have more windows then two, I want to switch each time to new window, how can I achieve this without holding alt?

Comment: Alt+ Esc would get your job done. Just have a try.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will switch you through a menu.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> will switch you directly through windows.

<kbd>Home</kbd> key will bring up a menu to select different windows with  your arrow keys or with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Using <kbd>Shift</kbd> in combination with any combination will reverse your selector's direction.

**<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> is probably your best option. Using xdotool will only remove the solution farther from the problem in most situations that directly interact with the desktop manager via short cuts.**