# Keyboard shortcut to move to next window

Tags: shortcut-keys, xdotool

I have a question much like this one:
[keyboard shortcut to switch to next window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066663/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-to-next-window)

I'm looking for a shortcut that allows me to cycle through the windows that are currently open. 
The reason why <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> does not work for me is that I'm trying to use gestures on my touchpad (they map to shortcuts/keystrokes). So I need to be able to have a gesture that always goes to the "next" window, or else I'm stuck cycling between the most recent two.

Does such a shortcut exist?

Thanks :)

EDIT: I'm currently using fusuma (https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma),
which itself uses xdotool

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ci6YbQGx3c4 may be useful if you have installed the 'Gestures' app https://gitlab.com/cunidev/gestures/blob/master/README.md outlined https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/09/linux-touchpad-gestures-app and at https://gitlab.com/cunidev/gestures/-/wikis/home Also see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xdotool.1.html

Comment: There is no direct function for this. It probably will require a script using `wmctrl` or `xdotool`.

Comment: Thanks guys! I think I will have a look at `wmctrl`, as this seems to be most likely to support what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure whether I understood your question correct, but the key combination to switch to the next window is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>. Perhaps you can bind your gesture to that key combination. (Previous window is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>).

Comment: Yes, when I reread what I wrote I also wasn't sure if anyone would understand what excactly I mean.
So basically I would like to have a circular queue of open windows. Then one gesture should go to the next window in that queue, and another to the previous window.

The problem is, that by hitting alt tab, the ordering of the windows changes. So hitting alt tab again switches back to the prevously focused window.
Using the keyboard this is not a problem, because I can just keep my finger on Alt, and cycle through by repeatedly hitting Tab. But with the gestures I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I don't think Alt needs to kept pressed. E.g: I see window1. Alt+tab+rightArrow shows window2. Release buttons. Alt+tab+rightArrow shows window3. Release buttons. Alt+tab+rightArrow shows window1.